# python + Semicolon written to file is written on the next line

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this simple python expression:

```
fscript.write (("update %s va set %s = %s where %s = %s;") % (argv[1],argv[2],vl[0],argv[3],vl[1]))
```

And I would expect to receive output like this

```
update some_table va set active_id = 1 where id = 5;
update some_table va set active_id = 1 where id = 3;
...more lines...
```

However, i'm getting this

```
update some_table va set active_id = 1 where id = 5
;update some_table va set active_id = 1 where id = 3
...more lines....
```

Anything i'm missing ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try adding a `strip()` to your latest parameter that could end with `\n`.

```
fscript.write (("update %s va set %s = %s where %s = %s;") % (argv[1],argv[2],vl[0],argv[3],vl[1].strip()))
```

Comment: Nice, didn't think about that.

Answer (score 1):

Some value of `vl[1]` is a string with a newline in it, not an integer.